# Module not found building Storybook in an Angular Nx Monorepo

Tags: typescript, webpack, storybook, nrwl

I am unable to build and run Storybook after adding it to an Nx Angular v11 project.  The project was recently migrated to Nx.  The project builds and serves without issue and I was able to add an e2e app without problem.

```
❯ npx nx build-storybook client

> nx run client:build-storybook

>  NX  ui framework: @storybook/angular


>  NX  Storybook builder starting ...

info => Cleaning outputDir: /repos/project/dist/storybook/client
info => Loading presets
info => Compiling manager..
info => Compiling preview..
info => Found custom tsconfig.json
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
info => Loading angular-cli config for angular lower than 12.2.0
info => Using angular project "client:build" for configuring Storybook
info => Using angular-cli webpack config
info => Loading custom Webpack config (full-control mode).
Starting type checking service...
(node:35617) DeprecationWarning: Default PostCSS plugins are deprecated. When switching to '@storybook/addon-postcss',
you will need to add your own plugins, such as 'postcss-flexbugs-fixes' and 'autoprefixer'.

See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-default-postcss-plugins for details.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
ERR! => Failed to build the manager
ERR! Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@storybook/addon-knobs/register' in '/repos/project'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@storybook/addon-knobs/register' in '/repos/project'
```

To add Storybook, I ran the following:

`nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration --name=client`

Below are some pertinent details about the resulting configuration without modification.

I suspect it is a webpack configuration issue. Can anyone spot what my issue is?  Thx.

```
❯ npx nx report

>  NX  Report complete - copy this into the issue template

  Node : 14.16.1
  OS   : darwin x64
  npm  : 7.24.2

  nx : Not Found
  @nrwl/angular : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/cli : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/cypress : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/devkit : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/express : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/jest : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/linter : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/nest : Not Found
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/storybook : 11.6.3
  @nrwl/gatsby : Not Found
  typescript : 4.0.8
```

```
❯ cat package.json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~1.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.15",
    "@nrwl/angular": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/cli": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/express": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/node": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "^11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/tao": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "11.6.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.3.12",
    ...
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
  },
...
```

```
❯ cat .storybook/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "exclude": [
    "../**/*.spec.js",
    "../**/*.spec.ts",
    "../**/*.spec.tsx",
    "../**/*.spec.jsx"
  ],
  "include": ["../**/*"]
}
```

```
❯ cat apps/client/.storybook/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": ["../**/*.spec.ts" ],
  "include": ["../src/**/*", "*.js"]
}
```

```
❯ cat .storybook/webpack.config.js
/**
 * Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Required<import('webpack').Configuration>} options.config
 * @param {'DEVELOPMENT' | 'PRODUCTION'} options.mode - change the build configuration. 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.
 */
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need

  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```

```
❯ cat apps/client/.storybook/webpack.config.js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const rootWebpackConfig = require('../../../.storybook/webpack.config');
/**
 * Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
 *
 * @param {Parameters<typeof rootWebpackConfig>[0]} options
 */
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  config = await rootWebpackConfig({ config, mode });

  const tsPaths = new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
    configFile: './tsconfig.base.json',
  });

  config.resolve.plugins
    ? config.resolve.plugins.push(tsPaths)
    : (config.resolve.plugins = [tsPaths]);

  return config;
};
```

```
❯ cat .storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-knobs/register'],
};
```

```
❯ cat apps/client/.storybook/main.js
const rootMain = require('../../../.storybook/main');

// Use the following syntax to add addons!
// rootMain.addons.push('');
rootMain.stories.push(
  ...['../src/app/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/app/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)']
);

module.exports = rootMain;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addon-knobs is deprecated anyway so try to remove it and install addon-controls instead
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-knobs

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this error is that addon-knobs does not have a register module.  It has a preset module.

Changing

```
addons: ['@storybook/addon-knobs/register']
```

to

```
addons: ['@storybook/addon-knobs/preset']
```

resolves the module not found error.

However, as @marko suggests, the better solution is to migrate to addon-controls.